# Share the list of lists in multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I want to increase the efficiency of my code. One intensive part of my code is to append elements to a list of lists. Basically, I want to do something as follows,

```
import multiprocessing
import time
def update_val(L, i):  
    L.append(i**2)
    return L

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = 1000000
    x_reg = [list(range(10)) for i in range(N)]
    y_reg = [list(range(10)) for i in range(N)]
    z_reg = [list(range(10)) for i in range(N)]   
    "Regular Call"
    start = time.time()
    [x_reg[i].append(i**2)  for i in range(N)]
    stat_reg =time.time() - start

    "Multiprocessing"
    num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count() # equals 4 in my case
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_cores)
    start = time.time()
    y_reg = pool.starmap(update_val,[(y_reg[i],i) for i in range(N)])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    stat_val =time.time() - start


    print("Regular: %g "%(stat_reg))
    print("Mult.: %g "%(stat_val))
```

The output is:

```
Regular: 0.387984 
Mult.: 2.54244
```

I believe the reason is related to how multiprocessing works; It needs to make a copy of the original list, do staff and return it. This should be the main reason why multiprocessing is very slow in my case. 
Here is my question:
1- How should I perform the same function to `z_reg` while sharing it between processes?
2- Does it enhance the performance.
3- Any other idea how to attach something to every sub-list in `z_reg`?

Comment: what is your python version?

Comment: It is python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes). Keep the lists in the main process, and send the data from all children processes through the Queue.

Comment: can you be more explicit? I am not sure how to use Queue in my setting.

Comment: @MehrdadMoharrami create the `Queue` and instead of passing the list to the subprocess, pass the created `Queue`. Then the subprocess can call `.put()` to put data in the queue while the main process stays in a loop calling `.get()` and receiving data, then `.append`ing it to the list you want. That way the lists are not shared - they stay in the main process.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But in my case, the only operation that I need to perform at each subprocess is to append a new element (no other operation involved at all, not even power or product). I see why you are suggesting using Queue (probably because of appending i**2 instead of i), but consider the case where the only operation that I need to do is to append 1 to the end of all lists. I wonder whether it is possible to append multiple elements at once instead of appending them one at a time.

Comment: sharing lists between processes can be done, but is not a good idea. It adds overhead as the entire list is copied around between processes @MehrdadMoharrami that is why I suggest keeping the lists in the main process. The Queue is a standard method of communication between processes, after using it to transfer the data to the main process you can add it to any lists you want in the main process.

Comment: I get your point. The problem is, the only operation I need to do is to append, that's it. I know it adds overhead @nosklo; what you are saying is related to my second question, does it worth it?
What I have in my mind is to share sublists between let's say 4 different processes and each of the processes attach a single element (let say an integer 1) to each sublist. I guess it might be impossible, but I do not have the knowledge to confirm that.

Comment: It is not impossible, but that means for every process that adds a single element the entire list has to be copied to all other processes @MehrdadMoharrami - even possible I wouldn't bother making such thing work because it is not what you want really

Comment: Thanks for clarification!